# How to add a view in "All site content view" on Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007

I see that on Sharepoint 2007, under "View All Site Content", I have Document Libraries, Lists, Picture Libraries etc all grouped up. 
How can I do such thing for another category?

[image]

I think I should add another view in here:

[image]

But how can I do that?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can not add any category here by NO-Code (OOB) way.

Now, if you are OK with creating farm level solution, then you have create custom application page and mimic this site content page plus add your category and replace existing site content page on run-time.

Here is the reference on, how to create custom application page.

[Creating an Application Page in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb418732(v=office.12).aspx)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! 
So basically I should modify the application page I have in the _layouts directory adding the category I want, right?
The problem is I cannot use Sharepoint Designer, is there any way I could edit that file without it? Is there any guide that can show exactly how to do what I want? The one you linked me is a bit difficult for me...

Comment: As I mentioned earlier this is application page. Application pages cannot be edited with sharepoint designer. I am sorry, but you need some advanced coding skill for achieving what you want. (knowledge of coding in sharepoint client object model). Unfortunately thats the only way i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Under **Navigation** in site settings you should be able to add a new category and the necessary links.